# Ошибка при разворачивании capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

Пытаюсь залить проект на сервер. В последний момент выдает ошибку. Проблема в **capistrano/deploy**

В логах вижу вот такую ситуацию

```
    ln -s /home/root/apps/holls_api/releases/20180509165931 /home/root/apps/holls_api/releases/current 
    mv /home/root/apps/holls_api/releases/current /home/root/apps/holls_api
 cannot overwrite directory '/home/root/apps/holls_api/current' with non-directory
```

Capistrano пытается переименовать папку, которая является симлинком. Как исправить?

**capfile**

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rvm'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require 'capistrano/rails/collection'
require 'capistrano3/postgres'
require 'capistrano/database_yml'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

install_plugin Capistrano::Puma
# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

**deploy.rb**

```
server 'xx.xx.xxx.xxx', port: 22, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true         
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:xxx/holls_api.git'

set :application,     'holls_api'
set :user,            'deploy'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false

set :stage,           :production
set :stages, ["production"]
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys:  ["#{ENV['USERPROFILE']}/.ssh/private.ppk"] }
set :postgres_keep_local_dumps, 5 # Will keep 5 last dump files.
set :postgres_backup_compression_level, 6 # Will use gzip level 6 to compress the output.

append :linked_files, 'config/database.yml'


set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

set :rails_env, "production"



namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end


namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  task :config_symlink do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "ln -nfs #{deploy_to}/shared/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
    end
  end


  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end


  #before 'deploy:starting', 'postgres:backup:create'
  #before 'deploy:starting', 'postgres:backup:download'

  before :starting,     :check_revision
#  before :compile_assets, :config_symlink
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart

end
```

**capistrano.log**

```
 INFO [c5b8e062] Running /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/root/apps/holls_api/releases/20180509165931 /home/root/apps/holls_api/releases/current on 92.53.107.196
     DEBUG [c5b8e062] Command: /usr/bin/env ln -s /home/root/apps/holls_api/releases/20180509165931 /home/root/apps/holls_api/releases/current
      INFO [c5b8e062] Finished in 0.176 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
      INFO [1b25514b] Running /usr/bin/env mv /home/root/apps/holls_api/releases/current /home/root/apps/holls_api on 22.33.137.196
     DEBUG [1b25514b] Command: /usr/bin/env mv /home/root/apps/holls_api/releases/current /home/root/apps/holls_api
     DEBUG [1b25514b]   mv:
     DEBUG [1b25514b]   cannot overwrite directory '/home/root/apps/holls_api/current' with non-directory
```

Comment: Надо начать с понимания почему /home/root/? зачем команды выполняются из под root? /home/root/.. или нужно /home/deploy/...

Answer (score 1):

У вас директория /home/root/apps/holls_api/current существует реально, а не в виде ссылки на на один из релизов /home/root/apps/holls_api/releases/20180509165931. В результате Capistrano не может заменить реально существующую директорию символической ссылкой.

Необходимо убрать директорию /home/root/apps/holls_api/current и передеплоить приложение.